# Manhua/manhwa/manga with female main character who goes back in time, aided by a dragon

Tags: story-identification, manga

I'm looking for a manhua/manhwa/manga where female main character is a hero that gets poisoned. Before she dies she goes to a dragon and ask him to turn back time.

When she goes back she is in her childlike appearance and finds out she is the daughter of the Emperor, and the dragon is with her and turns into the form of a cat.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11874/how-to-ask-a-good-anime-manga-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: @Mike - Was this in full colour or mostly black & white?

Answer (score 1):

This is *[How Did I Become the Princess?](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/how-did-i-become-the-princess)*, aka *Starting From Today, I'm a Princess?!*, a Korean manhwa from 2021.

> Once upon a time, ​​I was a weary, nameless warrior with neither family nor money. Some might say this was just my lot in life, but not me. When I am given the chance to return to the past, I take it, hoping to return to simpler times. However, after turning back time, I am shocked to learn that I am actually Princess Nanael, **the long lost daughter of the emperor of Ovyulia**. With my new name and new home, I’m dead-set on not losing my family ever again.

The main character is a hero that defeats the demon lord, and is subsequently poisoned by nobles that feared she'd betray them, so they try to get rid of her first. She contacts a dragon she met earlier and it grants her wish of turning back time. Upon re-awakening she discovers she's the emperor's daughter.

The dragon does stick around as a cat-like thing.

[image: Poisoning left, cat dragon right]